# Why appium not showing the child views with react native application on iOS

Tags: appium, react-native-ios

I’m facing trouble in identifying the child hierarchies in the appium. In ios, all child hierarchies are hidden when I did a spy via appium inspector with React native app.

In android I was able to see both the parent and child hierarchy. In appium forums what they mentioned was, changing the accessibility mode as false is the solution to get the child hierarchy in ios.

Without disabling the accessibility, is there any other solution to get it resolved?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? I am also facing the same.